# Accept commands in Java application, send from ASP.net web application

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, communication

I want to achieve some kind of remote control web application.

What I have now is a java application that runs on my computer. I want it to listen for commands from a web page, which I run in ASP.net on my own server. The Java application should do it's business, but at the same time listen for commands. If a command is recieved from the server, it should break what it is doing, and do what the command says.

Example:

*The Java application is currently feeding dogs. It gives them 1 treat every second.

*I navigate to my web application, and press the button "Feed cats 1 treat every second".

*The Java application stops feeding the dogs, and starts feeding the cats.

*I navigate to my web application again, and change the amount to 4 treats every second.

*The Java application changes the amount to 4 treats per second.

How would I approach the connection between the Java application and my ASP.net application? I've read about Sockets and Serversockets, but I'm a little unsure on what to use for this exact issue.

Comment: The right flow of information could be: 1. press click in browser 2. asp.net server is notified 3. the asp.net server updates db 4. your java app continuously polls the db for new information and gets that you clicked something in the browser 5. the java app do what the new command says

Comment: So you're suggesting that I put all data from the browser into a SQL database, and read the newest line from there?

Comment: No.. the asp.net server must get notified by the browser click - this can be done by submitting a form or via ajax. On the other end, the asp.net server may change something in a db or a file. Besides that, your java app should poll the same asp.net server for any changes. You don't have to use a db or even a file.. the change can be recorded even in memory used by the asp.net server

Comment: But using a DB would be beneficial if for example the ASP.NET app goes offline (crashes, maintenance, update, whatever). The Java Application could then still run with the last known configuration.